# Copy an Image to Clipboard in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

What is the equivalent for Clipboard.SetImage(Image) from System.Windows.Forms in Xamarin.Mac with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `WriteObjects` method on the NSPasteboard:

```
var image = someNSImage;
NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.ClearContents();
NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.WriteObjects(new NSImage[] { image });
```